# How to make a substitution that involves a nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to make a substitution for the variable $x$ from this.

```
 sub = {{x -> 2}, {x -> 5}}
```

I want to give to $x$ one of these two values, say $2$. If I write

$a)$     `x = sub [[1]][[1]][[2]]`

then it works but if I use instead

$b)$ `x = sub [[1]]`

or

$c)$     `x = sub [[1]][[2]]`

it doesn't and it crashes.

Is `sub` to be considered a nested list? If so, it is not clear the reason why $b)$ or $c)$ do not work, since if I need the first sublist of a nested list I simply write `list[[1]]`, right?

Where is my mistake?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `sub [[1]][[2]]` crashes because there is no part 2 to `sub[[1]]`. Go with `x /. sub[[1]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

So what was needed, if you wanted to go down that path, was `sub[[1,1,2]]` but the following is better:

```
x /. sub[[1]]

(* 2  *)
```